# Will changing the provisioning profile in XCode 9.1 force me to upload a new app (instead of updating an existing one) and lose my App Store history?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, xcode9.1

I recently upgraded to XCode 9.1. When I go to upload my app to iTunes in order to test under TestFlight, it will not let me upload after archiving because the name of the provisioning profile begins with XC, indicating that the profile is managed by XCode. In this thread:

[Xcode 9: Provisioning profile is Xcode managed, but signing settings require a manually managed profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358803/xcode-9-provisioning-profile-is-xcode-managed-but-signing-settings-require-a-m)

I learned that other people are running into the same problem. Even if I pick the XC profile in the upload tool it gives me the error message: "Profile is not Manually Managed", and I cannot upload the app.

Someone suggested renaming the provisioning profile, taking off the XC, used for distribution, but then I read this:

"If you change the provisioning profile and upload your app with this changed provisioning it'll be taken as new app, not as the update of existing app, because of the difference in provisioning."

from:

[How to safely rename iOS Distribution Profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766643/how-to-safely-rename-ios-distribution-profile)

The app I'm trying to update has been around a long time. I don't want to lose all of its history in iTunes.

Is there some way to work around this problem without losing all of the app's history? I have literally uploaded this app to iTunes hundreds of times but now I'm running into this problem for some reason. Is there some way to switch that profile to be Manually Managed? Is there any way to upload the app with an XCode managed provisioning profile, as I was doing?

Comment: I think, you can generate a new provisioning profile and use that manually. You must however keep the application identifier. Then you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Addition: the answers in these threads you mention make it sound as if a new app magically appears instead of the update. This is not going to happen. You would have to make a new app entry etc. So you can safely try your upload.